# Mod_Rewrite on but doesn't change URL Layout

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Hello I've got a problem with rewriting my URLs via .htaccess

*Php Info:*
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
*Hoster settings:*
Apache mod_rewrite ON

Current url Layout:

> http://www.xxxx.at/beitrag.php?thema=Bitcoins%20fuer%20jedermann%20gratis

Wanted:

> http://www.xxxx.at/beitrag/Bitcoins%20fuer%20jedermann%20gratis  (can
>   I change %20 to "-" maybe too?)

I've stup a .htacces which looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*)\.html$ /bitcoins.php?to=$1 [qsappend,L]
```

But the URL still looks the same, there is nothing changed.

Can someone help me please?
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+beitrag\.php\?thema=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /beitrag/%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bietrag/(.+)$ /bietrag.php?thema=$1 [L]
```

1. Turn off Multiviews so that `/beitrag` doesn't preemptively get served with `/beitrag.php`
2. The first rule matches the HTTP request line, gruops the query string, and redirects the browser so that the new URL shows up in the location bar
3. The second rule matches the new URL and internally rewrites it back to the one with the query string.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.